# Created Content types are not showing in List workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I created a content types.
I included that content types in a specific document library.
Now i need to generate a document in that doc library based on the choosen content type, through workflow.
When i tried to access those content type in workflow it shows empty space.

Please assist me how to solve this issue.
[image]

Comment: Check you parent content type for the content type you created. And whether it is a custom List or Document lib?

Comment: it is a document library. And the parent content type is document contenttype

Comment: Go to advance setting for the Doc lib allow inherit content type .

Comment: Do u mean this option? 
Allow management of content types?

Comment: Yes, please select YES OPTION

Comment: it is already Yes only

Comment: Still issue occurs. Please tell me if there is any other solution

Comment: You  cannot be allowed to set the OOB  contentTypeID through workflow, what you can do i think create a workflow variable with your CntnTypID. and set it to the wrkflow variable.

Comment: Hi, Iam unable to add that if i assign that contenttypeid in the specific variable. Because it shows only dropdown. Please check the above screen shots which i shared.

Comment: Hi, we solved this issue, This issue occurs due to one list has  not  been configured properly

Comment: Sound good.  Kudos!! :) #chitra